# Avoiding the newline when using UL

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm an "intermediate" CSS user but I'm having a problem that I can't seem to solve even though I suspect the answer will be surprisingly easy to fix from someone who knows more about css ...

I have a simple visual representation of a date who's markup is:

```
<ul class="visual-date">
    <li class="day-of-week text-muted">
        {{view.dayOfWeek}}
    </li>
    <li class="day-of-month">
        {{view.dayOfMonth}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

This displays the following:

[image]

with the following CSS:

```
.visual-date {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 85px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 1px 5px 1px;
    .day-of-week {
        background-color: #272927;
        color: white;
        font-size: 8pt;
        border-top-right-radius: 4px;
        border-top-left-radius: 4px;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #CBCDCA;
        border-style: solid;
    }
    .day-of-month {
        font-size: 24pt;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #CBCDCA;
        border-style: solid;
    }
}
```

That seems to work but what I'm struggling with is when I place this widget I can't get the text that follows to be on the same horizontal line but instead it is always dropped to the next line. Here's the complete code example:

http://codepen.io/kensnyder/full/uBAsl

So explicitly, what I'd like is for the "Today" text to be directly to the right of the visual date widget. Note, I am using Bootstrap 3.0 ... don't think this is creating any problems but possibly would change peoples thinking somewhat. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Semantically, I don't see why a date should even be a list. Why not the machine readable `<time>` and the human readable date inside in div/span tags?

Comment: You're right but UL .. LI is just my default for structured data even if it's generic semantically. I think the problem I'm describing is still the same though, right?

Comment: It probably doesn't affect anything in this case, but keep in mind that bootstrap may does some strange thing to lists to make them responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It drops to the next line because `ul` is inside a `div` which is a `block` element which means it fills up the whole width of its container. Anything after a `block` element is put below it.

You can fix this either by using `float` on the `block` element to get it to the left or right of content you want it to surround. Using `float: left;` on the `div` will float it to the left; however, the horizontal line will flow around it as well. You will need to apply a `clear: left;` on the horizontal line element for it to stop wrapping around left-floated elements.

```
.ember-view {
    float: left;
}
hr {
    clear: left;
}
```

You could also assign a different display type other than `block` to the `div` such as `inline-block`. However, since the `h1` containing "Today" is also a `block` element (`block` elements always start on a new line), you will need to set it to be `display: inline-block;` as well.

```
.ember-view {
    display: inline-block;
}
.ember-view + h1 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your `<ul>` is wrapped by a div, which is by default, a block level element and therefore it pushed all other elements to the bottom.

all you need to do is give this div: `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that in addition to the whole widget being inside a `div`, the `Today` text was inside a `h1` tag and both are by default `block` level elements.

Add the below to your CSS.

```
h1{
  display: inline-block;
}
#ember419{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[**CodePen Demo**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/Ckvgx)

**EDIT:** As pointed out in comments, `#ember419` seems to be an `id` dynamically assigned by EmberJS and hence it would not be a good option to use it as a selector. To overcome this, we can create a separate `class` with the `display: inline-block` property and attach it to the required element.

Comment: It may be not obvious from the question itself, but `#ember419` was added automatically by Ember application and will most probably change in the future. Using it as CSS selector is not a good idea.

Comment: Yes that's true @pavlo ... but I think the suggestion is correct outside the unstated context that you've called out. :)

Comment: @Pavlo: This is just a demonstration of what is the problem and *a* way to solve it. I understand your point and will see if I can modify it. By the way, was the down-vote by you?

Comment: @ken: I can put this on the `ember-view` class instead of `#ember419` but I notice there is another `div` also with the same class. Is there any other container kind of `div` with a unique selector?

Comment: First off I too was wondering about the downvoting, I think all the answers got one (and they were all largely right). Annoying. Anyway, let me textually thank you @Harry. Your answer was helpful.

Comment: wrt to 'ember-view' ... as one of the responders correctly associated this to **EmberJS**. I have solved the problem by creating a class called 'inline-block' and assigning to the Ember view (aka, `classNames: ['inline-block']`. In turn, I also assigned the `h1` tag to `.inline-block`. It all works great now.

Comment: @ken Ah yes, that would work out. But I am worried if other Ember views might get affected. Anyways glad to know that it has been solved. Cheers :)

Comment: As the assignment is specific to the `VisualDateView` the change should be localised to that view only.

Answer (score 0):

if you put

```
#ember419{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

and

```
h1{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

it works

```
inline-block
```

> Causes an element to generate an inline-level block container. The
>   inside of an inline-block is formatted as a block box, and the element
>   itself is formatted as an atomic inline-level box.